# How long will the nodes after insert into document cost to paint?

Tags: javascript, dom

I just want to get the nodes's render time when I insert 100000 nodes into document,I had tried few ways,but result unexpected.

Here is the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>node insert cost time test</title>
    <script>
        var st = Date.now();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Placehoder</h1>
<h1 id="h1"></h1>
<h1 id="h2"></h1>
<h1 id="h3"></h1>
<h1 id="h4"></h1>
<h1 id="h5"></h1>
<div id="box"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var en = Date.now();
    $("#h4").html("White cost time:" + (en - st));
</script>
<script>

    let data = [];
    for(let i =0;i<100000;i++){
      data.push({
         name:"test",
         age:18,
         gender:"female"
      }) 
    }

    
    const s = Date.now();
    let list = data;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        const ss = Date.now();
        if ($("#indexid-" + (list.length - 1)).size() > 0) {
            const findTime = new Date();
            const ft = + findTime;
            $("#h5").html(findTime)
            $("#h1").html(`The RealTime is ${findTime - s}`)
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1)
    const tpl = '<div id="indexid-{id}">' +
        '<h2>Name：{name}</h2>' +
        '<h4>Gender：{gender}</h4>' +
        '<h6>Age：{age}</h6>' +
        '</div>'
    let res = [];
    list.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.id = index;
        let str = tpl.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/gi, function ($, $1) {
            if (item[$1] + "") {
                return item[$1];
            }
            return ""
        })
        res.push(str);
    })
    //insert 100000 nodes into document
    //then get the nodes render time
    $("#box").html(res.join(""))
    const e = Date.now();
    $("#h2").html(`JS execute time：${e - s}ms`)
      
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works well on desktop browsers,but not on the mobileweb.
On mobile web,the output time is smaller than what it should be.I also used MutationObserver Api,but got the same result,could anyone help me?

Comment: When dealing with so many nodes, it's usually adviced to use some kind of pagination or partial rendering, since I doubt all 100k people will be visible on screen at the same time.

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: If you need better performance, then consider using "for loop" instead of `.forEach`.

Comment: leave performance aside,I just want to know if I insert many nodes into document,How long will these nodes take to flow or paint on the screen.
I JUST WANT TO GET THE TIME by some way,this is the only purpose.
As to 100000 nodes insert,this is just for describe the question.